# implicit parameter in implicit conversion

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct From{
    int i;
    From(){}
};

struct By{
    By(const From& f){}
};

struct To{
    To(const By& b){}
};

int main() {
    From f;
    To to = f;  // error: conversion from 'From' to non-scalar type 'To' requested
    // By by = f;
    // To to = by;
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to make this work without modifying `By` and `To` ?
And also without doing this :

```
 By by = f;
 To to = by;
```

Comment: Do you want the compiler to "understand" it's possible to convert `From` to `By` and then to `To`?, or do you want to not pass through `By` at all?

Comment: You can solve this if you create a wrapper class around this types.

Comment: @Amit of course it will use `By`'s constructor, but I want the compiler to do that for me !

Comment: @juanchopanza The point of implicit conversion, is that the compiler do things for you, for example here : https://ideone.com/OBSchN , in a function call, you don't need the object, the compiler does the conversion for you, what I need here is a double conversion, I know why he can't do this, but there may be a trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just provide a user-defined conversion operator in `From`:

```
struct From
{
    int i;
    From(){}
    operator To() const
    {
         To to;
         //fill it
         return to;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to make this work without modifying By and To ?

Yes. You can give `From` a conversion operator `To()`. This allows to convert `From` to `To` in a single user defined conversion:

```
struct From;
struct By;

struct To{
    To(const By& b){}
};

struct By{
    By(const From& f){}
};

struct From{
    int i;
    operator To() const { return To(By(*this)); }
    From(){}
};
```

Comment: Never say impossible, I know it creates a `B` object here too, but I meant an explicit instantiation, thank you

Answer (score -1):

I make no guarantees about its usefulness, but this snippet seems to do what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct From;

struct By{
    By(const From& f){}
};

struct From{
    int i;
    From(){}
    operator By() {}
};

struct To{
    To(const By& b){}
};

int main() {;
    From f;
    To to {f};  // error: conversion from 'From' to non-scalar type 'To' requested
    // By by = f;
    // To to = by;
    return 0;
}
```

I declared an implicit conversion operator in From without touching By or To; rearranged the declarations to appease the compiler; and changed the initialization syntax from "to = f" to "to {f}".

Please note that this is not scalable and cannot always be applied like this; there are limits to the number and type of conversions that can take place when the compiler is trying to fit together the pieces you give it.

***EDIT***: As has been pointed out to me, the only change that was actually significant here was the switch from copy-initialization to direct-initialization. I'll leave the code above as-is, but the conversion operator is unnecessary in my example.

Comment: Only under GCC 4.9; -Wall complains about unused parameters and missing return statements, but nothing else.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/vyz2VA. Your conversion only works because you're doing something else. For which you don't even need the conversion.

Comment: Well, I feel stupid now. I made that change without even thinking about the semantic implications; thanks for pointing out my oversight.

Comment: @acwaters: there's no need to feel stupid. (Almost) never.